# Htaccess taugh redirection rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have to create such a redirection rule in HTACCESS that changes the first part of the URL (from "confindustria/verona/news.nsf/($linkacross)" to "new.bestrank.it/gate/news/documento?openform&id="), keeps unchanged the ID ("879D9288439B4C42C12588E1004BD915&restricttocategory=Credito%20Finanza%20Assicurazioni") but extracts a static piece of it in the middle ("?opendocument").

From

`https://old.bestrank.it/confindustria/verona/news.nsf/($linkacross)/879D9288439B4C42C12588E1004BD915?opendocument&restricttocategory=Credito%20Finanza%20Assicurazioni`

to:

`https://new.bestrank.it/gate/news/documento?openform&id=879D9288439B4C42C12588E1004BD915&restricttocategory=Credito%20Finanza%20Assicurazioni`

How should I write the rules for this?

The best I came up with is the following:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/confindustria/verona/news.nsf/($linkacross)/( 879D9288439B4C42C12588E1004BD915)?opendocument(&restricttocategory=Credito%20Finanza%20Assicurazioni)/?\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^  https://new.bestrank.it/gate/news/documento?openform&id=%1%2? [R=301,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following .htaccess rules file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Either use following Rules OR use rules of OR here, use them one at a time only please.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/old-path/(id-3434)-newfolder(-5455)/?\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^  https://new-domain.com/new-path/%1%2? [R=301,NC,L]
```

---

---

***OR*** as ***a Generic rules***(not hardcoding digits after `id`) try following:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/old-path/(id-\d+)-newfolder(-\d+)/?\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^  https://new-domain.com/new-path/%1%2? [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: It didn't work becuase I think I have brakets in my original URL....so it looks like old-domain.com/old-(path)/id-3434-newfolder-5455 I think the system thinks that part of the url in brakets is a special character....is there any way to avoid it? THANK YOU

Comment: Here are the original urls to redirect:

https://old.bestrank.it/confindustria/verona/news.nsf/($linkacross)/879D9288439B4C42C12588E1004BD915?opendocument&restricttocategory=Credito%20Finanza%20Assicurazioni
to:
https://new.bestrank.it/gate/news/documento?openform&id=879D9288439B4C42C12588E1004BD915&restricttocategory=Credito%20Finanza%20Assicurazioni

Comment: I didn't want to put them initially because they're too long but I followed the scheme and it didn't work so maybe you can help me with those. THANKS YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: @RomanSadovnik, could you please do explain more on what's not working, cheers.

Comment: the code that you wrote is correct! thank you. the problem is that the original url that I have to redirect (I didn't write it initially to not complicate things) contains brakets ($linkacross). I edited my post putting the real URLs that I have to redirect. I would infinitely appreciate your help! Roman.